# How to implement shareplex_ignore_trans in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

What does source and target mean in shareplex_ignore_trans.
We are migrating oracle procedure to postgres.
Please suggest ?

Comment: What does this `shareplex_ignore_trans` procedure do? What problem are you trying to solve? What is the code that isn't working?

Comment: We are migrating from oracle to postgres. In oracle procedure we have shareplex_ignore_trans I dont have idea what this actually do